# How does firebase-authentication work

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

**Code from firebase 3 docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user**

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
          if (user) {
            // If there's a user take him to the home page.
            this.rootPage = HomePage;
          } else {
            // If there's no user logged in send him to the LoginPage
            this.rootPage = LoginPage;
          }
  });
```

How is the `user` parameter set in the observer and how is the code above different from this below?

**Code from tutorial @ http://javebratt.com/firebase-3-email-auth/**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            // If there's a user take him to the home page.
            this.rootPage = HomePage;
          } else {
            // If there's no user logged in send him to the LoginPage
            this.rootPage = LoginPage;
          }
    });
```

The reason I am asking is that, I going through a tutorial for ionic 2 and firebase 3 and the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` implementation is clearly different from what is in the official docs for firebase 3

Answer (score 0):

The user parameter is set with var user = rootRef.getAuth();

Here's how I have used it.

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://yourapp.firebaseio.com');

// Check the current user login status and redirect if not logged in
var user = rootRef.getAuth();
if (user) {
   var user = rootRef.getAuth();
   var userRef = rootRef.child('users').child(user.uid);
   ... do something with the logged in user...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @MattHannam your explanation looks to be for the recently deprecated firebase 2

Answer (score 0):

The 2 are similar in that the first uses a callback function and the second an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). E.g.: these are the same (as an example):

```
var a = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });
var b = a.map( s => s.length );
```

When the user is authenticated with firebase3 it will pass some data back in the callback or arrow function. This data is accessible under the user variable in your example. You can do a console.log(user) to see which objects are passed on (like authentication id, provider, email ...).

Hope this points you in the right direction.